# RecyclerView not displaying data when Asynchronous operations performed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

```
public class ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private static List<ProfileSearchResult> profileList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<ProfileSearchResult> profileListNew = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;public ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
public void notifyChanges(List<ProfileSearchResult> changes){
    profileListNew.addAll(changes);
    AsyncTaskRunner taskRunner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    taskRunner.execute();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_result_profile_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    RequestOptions profilePictureRequest = new RequestOptions();
    profilePictureRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.index);
    holder.name.setText(profileList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tag.setText(profileList.get(position).getTagline());
    Glide.with(context)
        .applyDefaultRequestOptions(profilePictureRequest)
        .load(profileList.get(position).getProfilePictureUrl())
        .into(holder.thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return profileList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View view;
    public CircleImageView thumbnail;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView tag;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

        name = view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_name);
        tag = view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_tagline);
        thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_thumbnail);
    }
}


private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<List<ProfileSearchResult>, Void, Void> {

    /**
     * This method compares profileSearchResultChanges with profileList to add new files,
     * remove deleted files and  modify files (remove old version of a file and add it's new version)
     * Asynchronously
     * @param lists
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<ProfileSearchResult>... lists) {

        Iterator<ProfileSearchResult> iter = profileList.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

            if(false == profileListNew.contains(result)){
                profileList.remove(result);
            }
        }
        iter = profileListNew.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

            if(false == profileList.contains(result)){
                profileList.add(result);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        invalidate();
    }
}
public void invalidate(){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

This is the adapter class for my recyclerview. As Livedata registers an update for query snapshot, I pass the document to the adapter. When I assign

```
profileList = changes;
```

in notifyChanges() without any asynchronous operation, my recyclerview displays data. But when I do the Asynchronous operations, the RecyclerView is empty. What could be the reason? Thanks in advance

```
05-30 18:27:07.813 13453-14405/com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
Process: com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy, PID: 13453
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.adapters.ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter.java:96)
    at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.adapters.ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(ProfileSearchRecyclerAdapter.java:82)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from any other thread than main thread. Just remove calls to `invalidate()` from `doInBackground()` and instead add it to `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    Log.w("PROCESS EXECUTED", String.valueOf(profileList.size()));
    invalidate();
}
```

ArrayList should not be modified when iteration over it. Instead of using `remove()` method on ArrayList, use `remove()` method on Iterator.

```
Iterator<ProfileSearchResult> iter = profileList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

    if(false == profileListNew.contains(result)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Also you may be running multiple AsyncTasks concurrently which may throw ConcurrentModificationException, so you should synchronize operations on lists by using lock so that only one thread can modify list at a time. Add this synchronized block to `doInBackground()` in your AsyncTask like this

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(List<ProfileSearchResult>... lists) {
    synchronized (profileList) {
        Iterator<ProfileSearchResult> iter = profileList.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

            if(false == profileListNew.contains(result)){
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        iter = profileListNew.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

            if(false == profileList.contains(result)){
                profileList.add(result);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

I'm getting this error too!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SachinTitus Can you post full stack trace?

Comment: Sure.. One second

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem of the `ConcurrentModificationException` is here

```
Iterator<ProfileSearchResult> iter = profileList.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ProfileSearchResult result = iter.next();

            if(false == profileListNew.contains(result)){
                profileList.remove(result); // <------- here <-------
            }
        }
```

In java if you wish to remove an element from a list while using its iterator you must use the iterator's method to do so or face the `ConcurrentModificationException`

It's mostly a protection mechanism to reassure the iterator won't pass twice on the same list node or skip a node. [docs link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

instead of `profileList.remove(result);`

try `iter.remove()`

check this [example](https://www.java-examples.com/remove-element-collection-using-java-iterator-example)

Hope this helps